# 2D random points under a curve in c++

Tags: c++, random

I want to choose 50 random points between x-axis and curve y=sin (x)+2 (for example). I want random points to be spread uniformly in this 2D region. I did like this:

```
using namespace std;
double randnum (double aa, double bb)  //defining a function to create random numbers
{
  static std::default_random_engine generator;
  std::uniform_real_distribution<double> distribution (aa,bb);
  return distribution(generator);
}
   for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
            {
            x[i] = randnum(0,2 * M_PIl);
            y[i] = randnum(0,sin(x[i])+2);
            }
```

But it is not correct because it gives points denser in regions which curve is closer to the x-axis. How can I choose points with equal density in the domain?

Comment: what do you mean spread uniformly ? Then they are not random anymore !

Comment: I mean in regions which curve is closed to x_axis, I need less number of points. Am I making sense? @farbiondriven

Comment: @farbiondriven I think he means uniformly sampled where the probability of a point being in a region is proportional to the region's area

Comment: You speak about uniformity in a 2D region, do you want them to be uniform in a x-axis range o in a real 2D region? Because for the latter just tossing random numbers won't be enough since you want to distribute them on a plane, not on an axis

Comment: o in a real 2D region @Jack

Comment: Then there is no simple solution to the problem since each function will distribute them in a different way. Actually having 50 points distrbuted uniformly in a 2D plane doesn't make sense in areas in which the function won't be defined. How do you plan to treat them? What do you need to do with this data? This sounds an xy problem to me.

Comment: Ok now it's more clear. What is the domain ? And the resolution ? Let's say you compute from 0 to 2pi and you divide the domain in n samples. Then you can make the function to select how many point should stand under each region.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not squeeze the same number/probability of points under the lower parts of the function.
Instead make random points in the rectangle area over x-range up to max y.
But ignore those which are too high on the y axis.

I.e. replace your loop by this one:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++) 
{
    do
    {   x[i] = randnum(0,2 * M_PIl);
        y[i] = randnum(0,3); // three is max-y, but not really relevant
    } while (y[i]>=sin(x[i])+2);
}
```